# Play Framework Azure SQL database connection.

Tags: java, azure, jdbc, playframework-2.0

I have a Java Playframework application that I am currently hosting on Azure CloudService. I managed to deploy my application to Azure using this tutorial https://msopentech.com/blog/2014/09/25/tutorial-running-play-framework-applications-microsoft-azure-cloud-services-2/

But now I would like to connect the application to SQL database I have set up in my Azure account.

My database configure is like this:

```
db.default.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlserver://lunbjmhvc8.database.windows.net:1433;database=hcakathon-tripplanner;"
db.default.user="MyUsername"
db.default.password="MyPassword"
```

When I run the application locally I always get:

```
Cannot connect to database [default]
```

When deployed to Azure I get "This webpage is not available". 
Anyone that have solved similar problem?

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: I did not find any solution to this problem :/

Comment: I've found something, I upgraded the SQLJDBC version to 4.1 from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774 and you have to set up the firewall as well on azure by allowing the IP-s you want to use